# How to perform cartesian transformation

Tags: c++, geometry, coordinate-transformation

I am led to believe a Cartesian Transformation is what I need, but I am not sure. Here is my problem.

I have two coordinate systems one Global x,y,z another local i,j,k that exists inside of x,y,z

I know the location of origin point of the Local system inside of the global. Let's label it B.

I know two more points C and E along the axis i and j. Meaning my axis i can be defined by the line BC and the axis j by the line BE. Axis k will be perpendicular to the 2D plan i,j

How do I translate the coordinates of one system to the other.

For example say I know D{x,y,z}, I know D exists within the the local coordinate system, how do I get D{i,j,k}? Also how do I go back in the other direction?

How to:
D{x,y,z} <-> D{i,j,k}

Comment: If you need help with the mathematics then ask on the corresponding mathematics site.

Answer (score 2):

The affine transformation is defined by the 3×1 translation vector *B* and a 3×3 rotation matrix *E*. Now you want to take a local point `P=(i_P,j_P,k_P)` and transform it to a global point `P'=(x_P,y_P,z_P)`. This is done by

```
    P' = B + E * P
```

1. The translation is simple, `B=(B_x, B_y, B_z)`
2. The rotation matrix is defined as the global coordinates of the unit vectors `i`, `j` and `k` as the three columns of the matrix.

   ```
       | i_x  j_x  k_x |
   E = | i_y  j_y  k_y |
       | i_z  j_z  k_z |
   ```

To find these components use the coordinates of points `B=(B_x, B_y, B_z)`, `C=(C_x, C_y, C_z)` and `E=(E_x, E_y, E_z)`

1. Take the difference between *C* and *B* and make it a unit vector for `i`. Find the distance between them as

   ```
   d_BC = sqrt( (B_x-C_x)^2 + (B_y-C_x)^2 + (B_z-C_z)^2 );
   ```

   and the components are:

   ```
   i_x = (C_x-B_x)/d_BC;
   i_y = (C_y-B_y)/d_BC;
   i_z = (C_z-B_z)/d_BC;
   ```
2. Take the difference between *E* and *B* and make it a unit vector for `j`. Find the distance between them as

   ```
   d_BE = sqrt( (B_x-E_x)^2 + (B_y-E_x)^2 + (B_z-E_z)^2 );
   ```

   and the components are:

   ```
   j_x = (E_x-B_x)/d_BE;
   j_y = (E_y-B_y)/d_BE;
   j_z = (E_z-B_z)/d_BE;
   ```
3. The components of `k` are found using a vector cross product `k = i × j`

   ```
   k_x = i_y*j_z - i_z*j_y;
   k_y = i_z*j_x - i_x*j_z;
   k_z = i_x*j_y - i*y*j_x;
   ```

The full transformation is now

```
x_P = B_x + i_x*i_P + j_x*j_P + k_x*k_P;
y_P = B_y + i_y*i_P + j_y*j_P + k_y*k_P;
z_P = B_z + i_z*i_P + j_z*j_P + k_z*k_P;
```

**Edit 1**

The reverse transformation is

```
    P = E'*(P'-B)
```

where `E'` is the transpose of the 3×3 matrix `E`. In component form this is

```
i_P = i_x*(x_P-B_x) + i_y*(y_P-B_y) + i_z*(z_P-B_z);
j_P = j_x*(x_P-B_x) + j_y*(y_P-B_y) + j_z*(z_P-B_z);
k_P = k_x*(x_P-B_x) + k_y*(y_P-B_y) + k_z*(z_P-B_z);
```

Comment: Hi @ja72 I would like to sincerely thank you for your help and exceptionally thorough answer. I am much more concerned with xyz->ijk than the other way around, how might I alter this equation to that end? I will study your information to see if i can get the answer myself.
I wanted to PM you to thank you personally and also to let you know a little more about the project you helped and to see if there was a way that I may be able to credit your contribution. Alas stackoverflow does not allow such a thing, so please feel free to contact me at chrisbay90@gmail.com

Comment: See edit for the reverse transformation. If you feel like it please credit me as SO user [`ja72`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/380384/ja72) and link to my profile.